# GoogleMaps GPSV.2 only to be tested in real devices?

Tags: android, google-maps

I was testing the implementation of Google Maps from Google Play Service V2 and following carefully this [suggestion](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) and from developer.android.com. Setting virtual device Android 3.1 (API level 12) and running it, the maps weren't shown, instead this message is shown on the screen "this app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from this tablet" and  LogCat says 04-26 21:47:39.449: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(395): Google Play Store is missing" in orange text. After that, reading somewhere at internet, apparently it must be tested in a real device, is that true?. Let me do another question, can I run that application in my Tablet w/Android 2.2.1 anyway?, if not, what modifications must I do in the project?. I'm using Eclipse indigo in Ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> After that, reading somewhere at internet, apparently it must be tested in a real device, is that true?

No emulator ships with support for the Play Store. You will find various people advocating software piracy as a workaround.

> can I run that application in my Tablet w/Android 2.2.1 anyway?

If that tablet has OpenGL 2.0 and the Play Services Framework, yes.

Comment: My Tablet came with its google maps application and runs well. About the OpenGL issue, I don't know if this is supported, I will try to run an application that uses OpenGL and see what happens.

Comment: I followed the steps 1,2,3 from [here](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/#comment-8364) and remove google play lib from project dependencies, just appears android-support-v4.jar only. But this f****ng error is shown:
`E/AndroidRuntime(918): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public`
 why this? if I've installed that package?